# DropDownList yii 2.0 example

Tags: yii2, yii-components

I am using yii 2.0 Framework.
How i can make options from my database. 
I found this, but it's yii 1.1:

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('listname', $select, 
          array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female'));
```

I want to pass it to form:

```
<?php $form->dropDownList() ?>
```

How i can fill my dropdownlist from my database table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `yii\helpers\Html` it contains `Html::dropDownList()`.

```
echo Html::dropDownList('listname', $select, ['M'=>'Male', 'F'=>'Female']);
```

Check [Yii Framework 2.0 API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail)

**Controller**

```
public function actionSomething() {
    $sexes = ['M'=>'Male', 'F'=>'Female'];  
    $this->render('yourView', ['sexes'=>$sexes]);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
::
    echo Html::dropDownList('listname', $select, $sexes);
::
?>
```

Comment: I am using ActiveForm widget, is it possible to pass parameters there? What is the best way? Create and array in controller, I am out of english examples (:

Comment: You can create the array in the controller, but I usually create the array in the view. Are the dropdown values stored in the database or is it just an unstored list of values?

Comment: Yes, values are stored in database. Can you make an example of how to pass them from controller?

Comment: I see in you question that the select values come from a database tabel. Create a model with a method .f.i. `getSexes()` that return the array.

Answer (score 13):

If you use ActiveForm widget use this:

```
<?php 
    $items = ArrayHelper::map(Model::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
    $form->field($model, 'attribute')->dropDownList($items)
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes if you use ActiveForm widget , u dont have to change anything in the controller , in views, in the form, add this where u want the dropdown

```
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

    <?php 
        $city = \app\models\City::find()->all(); 
        $listData=ArrayHelper::map($city,'cityId','cityName'); 
    ?>    
    <?= $form->field($model, 'cityId')->dropDownList($listData,['prompt'=>'Choose...']) ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name_of_field')->dropdownList(['1' => 'aaa', '2' => 'bbb'], ['prompt' => '---Select Data---']) ?>
```