# Selected value in a dropdown list Yii2

Tags: yii2

could someone tell me how to create a `selected` value in dropdown list?

Here is my dropdown list:

```
       <?= Html::dropDownList(
        'calculation-type',
        $calculateByMonths,
        $calculationTypeList, [
        'options' => [
            Employee::DISABLED =>[
                'disabled' => true,
                'selection' => true
            ]
        ],
        'id' => 'calculation-type',
    ]); ?>
```

That line `selection => true` doesn't work, I don't know why :( Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DropDownList yii 2.0 example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594074/dropdownlist-yii-2-0-example)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [official Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail) second argument in `Html::dropDownList` is `$selection`, and it has to contain string or array of selected **values**.

Values in dropDownList are keys in `$items` array. For example, if you have an array of months and you need to make February `selected`:

```
<?php

$month = [
    'jan' => 'January',
    'feb' => 'February',
    'mar' => 'March',
    'apr' => 'April',
];

echo \yii\helpers\Html::dropDownList(
    'months', //name of your select tag
    'feb', // selected option value
    $month // array of items
);
?>

<!-- Output of the dropDownList-->
<select name="months">
    <option value="jan">January</option>
    <option value="feb" selected>February</option>
    <option value="mar">March</option>
    <option value="apr">April</option>
</select>
```